# Update Field with variable meteor mongo

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have one collection called "Towns" with this document inside:

```
{
    "_id" : "vK4PvdNBfBbdv92PH",
    "ownerId" : "J8MpsWChPQdET6jwQ",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-07-04T07:25:28.406Z"),
    "spot1" : {
        "construction" : false,
        "constructingBuildingName" : "",
        "buildingName" : "factory",
        "level" : 1,
        "startTime" : 0,
        "finishTime" : 0
    },
    "spot2" : {
        "construction" : false,
        "constructingBuildingName" : "",
        "buildingName" : "",
        "level" : 0,
        "startTime" : 0,
        "finishTime" : 0
    },
    "spot3" : {
        "construction" : false,
        "constructingBuildingName" : "",
        "buildingName" : "",
        "level" : 0,
        "startTime" : 0,
        "finishTime" : 0
    }
}
```

What i am trying to do is update in this case spot2s fields with variables.

spotName variable defines which spot field to update.
update startTime, finishTime, constructingBuildingName, change construction to true

```
'buildNewBuilding': function (userid, buildingid, spotnumber) {
    var spotName = "spot" + spotnumber.toString();
    var data = Buildings.find({_id: buildingid}).fetch();
    var constructingBuildingName = data[0].name;
    var startTime = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
    var finishTime = startTime + data[0].time;


    Towns.update({ownerId: userid}, {}) //??
    //update startTime,finishTime,constructingBuildingName,change construction to true

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should reconsider the data structure you have. Having numbered keys is usually not recommended. It would be better in your case to use an Array of spots to get better benefits from mongo request engine.

The only case when you should keep your structure is if you are 100% certain not to need to have 4 spots per Town.

```
{
    "_id" : "vK4PvdNBfBbdv92PH",
    "ownerId" : "J8MpsWChPQdET6jwQ",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-07-04T07:25:28.406Z"),
    "spots" : [
        {
            "name": "spot1",
            "construction" : false,
            "constructingBuildingName" : "",
            "buildingName" : "factory",
            "level" : 1,
            "startTime" : 0,
            "finishTime" : 0
        },
        {
            "name": "spot2",
            "construction" : false,
            "constructingBuildingName" : "",
            "buildingName" : "",
            "level" : 0,
            "startTime" : 0,
            "finishTime" : 0
        },
        {
            "name": "spot3",
            "construction" : false,
            "constructingBuildingName" : "",
            "buildingName" : "",
            "level" : 0,
            "startTime" : 0,
            "finishTime" : 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Then,I advise you get a look inside the [mongoDB documentation here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#update-embedded-documents-using-multiple-field-matches). It explains how to do such an update using `$elemMatch`

```
'buildNewBuilding': function (userid, buildingid, spotnumber) {
    var spotName = "spot" + spotnumber.toString();
    var data = Buildings.find({_id: buildingid}).fetch();
    var constructingBuildingName = data[0].name;
    var startTime = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
    var finishTime = startTime + data[0].time;


    Towns.update({ownerId: userid, spots: {$elemMatch: {name: spotName}}}, {$set: {
        "spots.$.constructingBuildingName": constructingBuildingName,
        "spots.$.startTime": startTime,
        "spots.$.finishTime": finishTime,
        "spots.$.construction": true,
    }}) 


}
```